# Element is not clickable at point Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

I have the following code and I cannot figure out how to click on an element without getting  `"Element is not clickable at point"` error message.

You can also see that I am moving to the element before clicking it. The following code sample should fully work.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
    , By = webdriver.By
    , until = webdriver.until;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
driver.get('http://www.vapeworld.com/');
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, 3000);
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    try {
        driver.executeScript("try{jQuery('[name=\"" + i.toString() + "_name\"]')[1].click()}catch(Ex){};");
    }
    catch (Ex) {}
}
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('search')).sendKeys('pax 2'); //to enter text
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('button search-button')).click();
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('product-collection-image-2270')).then(function (element) {
    driver.actions().mouseMove(element).perform();
    driver.sleep(5000);
    driver.actions().click(element).perform();        
});
driver.quit();
```

Comment: What's the full error message? The key to determining how to fix it is in that message because that message tells you what element is blocking the click. Figure out what the element is, a dialog or some other popup?, and deal with it. Once you do that, your probably will likely be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with `.executeScript()` to perform click as below :-

Just change this line :

```
driver.actions().click(element).perform();
```

to this :

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element)
```

Hope it will work..:)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to `click` on 'button search-button', make sure that no element is over lapping on your `click` element.
Check whether your search results for 'pax 2' is overlapping the `click` element or not.
If so, then `click` on some other element which doesn't get overlapped due to search and make sure that `click` doesn't make any changes on the page as you don't want it. (try by clicking on some label element)
And then try `click` on the element you want.

Comment: The search click one is working. The one that is not working is driver.actions().click(element).perform();

Comment: Yes, i get that, just check whether your search results are covering the element on which you need to click.